# Remove "From computer" media tab for posts with existing attachments?

Tags: wp-admin, attachments, post-editor

On editing the attachments of a post whith at least one attachment previously uploaded, how do I remove the *From computer* tab and redirect to the *Gallery* tab?

[image: The "Add an Image" tabs]

This is my current code:

```
add_filter('media_upload_tabs','remove_medialibrary_tabs', 99);
function remove_medialibrary_tabs($tabs) {
    if ($post_id = (isset($_REQUEST['post_id']) ? $_REQUEST['post_id'] : false)) {
        if (count(get_posts("post_type=attachment&post_parent={$post_id}"))>0) {
            // MY QUESTION
        }
    }

    unset($tabs['type_url']);
    unset($tabs['library']);

    return $tabs;
}
```

Comment: I don’t understand your question. Could you add a screenshot and mark the element you want to remove?

Comment: When you edit some post, theres an icon to attach images or media to a post. On that modal window, I need to redirect the user to the Gallery tab (not the From computer tab) if the post has at least one attachmet previously uploaded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To remove the *From Computer* tab *header*, you unset [the `type` key from that array](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1/wp-admin/includes/media.php#L16). However, this will (confusingly) not remove the tab *content*, and because this is the default tab it will show it even if the tab header for it is gone.

To change the default tab you must hook into [the `media_upload_default_tab` filter](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1/wp-admin/media-upload.php#L110). This gets called in multiple places, I did not research which one is called in which circumstances, so I moved the check for attachments to a separate function and rewrote your code like this:

```
add_filter('media_upload_tabs','wpse13567_media_upload_tabs', 99);
function wpse13567_media_upload_tabs( $tabs ) {
    if ( wpse13567_post_has_attachments() ) {
        unset( $tabs['type'] );
    }
    unset( $tabs['type_url'] );
    unset( $tabs['library'] );

    return $tabs;
}

add_filter( 'media_upload_default_tab', 'wpse13567_media_upload_default_tab' );
function wpse13567_media_upload_default_tab( $tab )
{
    if ( wpse13567_post_has_attachments() ) {
        return 'gallery';
    }
    return $tab;
}

function wpse13567_post_has_attachments()
{
    static $post_has_attachments = null;
    if ( null === $post_has_attachments && $post_id = (isset($_REQUEST['post_id']) ? $_REQUEST['post_id'] : false) ) {
        $post_has_attachments = count(get_posts("post_type=attachment&post_parent={$post_id}"))>0;
    }
    return $post_has_attachments;
}
```